# javascript files not loading on first load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am currently working on an angularjs project that uses moment.js and fullcalendar. the problem i am experiencing is when a user first loads the page the calendar doesn't show up, as soon as i press refresh it loads and i believe it to be down to being stored in cache.

i am using $ocLazyLoad and i think it could be to do with this.

```
 loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                    {
                        insertBefore: '#loadBefore',
                        files: ['css/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css','js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js']
                    },
                    {
                        files: ['js/plugins/moment/moment.min.js']
                    },
                    {
                        files: ['js/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js']
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ui.calendar',
                        files: ['js/plugins/fullcalendar/calendar.js']
                    },
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with $ocLazyLoad, but would you need to put `insertBefore: '#loadBefore'` in moment, bootstrap and calendar to make sure you have everything loaded before DOM elements start to load?

Comment: @PatrickBarr i tried that but not luck, if i clear cache the error occurs and doesnt show on refresh. But as soon as i press enter on the url it loads